# A connection manager has not been assigned to the IDbConnection in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using SSIS to import data from txt file to a sql server. I have created the package and did the following items
1. Created a Credential -> I gave my login credential
2. Created Proxy
3. Created Job. Assigned the Step1 to the proxy

While running in the VS2010, package is running correctly and datas are getting imported to the table. But when running as a job I am getting the following error.

**`3-23 20:14:04.96     Code: 0xC0208035     Source: Data Flow Task ADO NET Destination [2]     Description: A connection manager has not been assigned to the IDbConnection.  End Error  Error: 2015-03-23 20:14:04.96     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: ADO NET Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208035.  End Error  Error: 2015-03-23 20:14:04.96     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2015-03-23 20:14:04.96     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  8:14:04 PM  Finished: 8:14:04 PM  Elapsed:  0.062 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.`**

Can any one tell me where am I doing wrong? Is this is a problem with credentials?

Comment: How is your destination connection configured? Do you use configuration files? Are you using username / passwd or integrated security?

Comment: Configured through connection manager. Created ADO.Net connection manager and mapped the ADO.Net Dest to this connection manager

Comment: To exclude credential issues, you can create a proxy account in the agent and run the jobstep using this proxy. In there you can use your own account.